# Erro occur when i POST Request to REST api

Tags: ios, xcode, rest

i want to send **POST** Request in **REST api** but when i see in server side send an error message receive like this type-.

```
**{"messages":{"error":[{"code":404,"message":"Request does not match any route."}]}}**
```

this error is occurs.
and my program code is here-

```
NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"postBody=%@",@"Rama"];
 NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[post length]];

 NSURL *myURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://developer.b24solutions.com/grocery/api/rest/"];
 NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:myURL                                                           cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                                   timeoutInterval:0.0];

 [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
 [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];


[request setHTTPBody:[post dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
NSURLConnection *clearSession = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
[clearSession start];
NSLog(@"%@",clearSession);
if(clearSession){
    NSLog(@"data send");
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"connection failed");
}
```

so where i am going wrong.
please help me.
and in server side work on php at same url.

```
 <?php
$result = $_POST['postBody'];


echo $result;
```

?>

Comment: @DharmeshDhorajiya: then what i can do now.

Comment: @DharmeshDhorajiya-you are correct..so now i develop a page  [link]:(developer.b24solutions.com/grocery/api/rest/new.html)
 .and than go furthur..thanks dear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

error code 404 means file not fount. your api link not file name exits. please add full api path for example

[developer.b24solutions.com/grocery/api/rest/yourfilename](http://developer.b24solutions.com/grocery/api/rest/yourfilename)

Because this link not work in browser. You code is correct but incorrect api link.

```
NSURL *myURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://developer.b24solutions.com/grocery/api/rest/giveyourfilenamewithextension"];
```